How to get from a description or pseudo-code of some FSM into its represented data path and control?
(I might be wrong about some of the terminology as I'm not learning it in English, I'll do my best but take it with a pinch of salt)
I need to do some problems of the sort explained below, what I don't understand is how I get from the question/instruction/pseudo-code into the blocks of basic units (registers, ALUs, etc...) their data path and their control.
I provided the example with exactly the "missing step" for me.
In the example below from our lectures, you can see that the required machine receives each "time" some number represented by (let's say) 32 bits, the first element different from 0 will indicate the number of elements in the list.
(it's translated from Google Translate - supposed to say "...receives serially a series of numbers (each one represented in the same number of bits - unspecified) and calculates their sums")

and the slide right after he presented us with the following implementation, without explaining how he got to it:

After looking at his implementation I can see that it works, but I don't know how to get to it.
So to summarize I don't know (in general) how to get from the first pic to the second (from the pseudo-code to the hardware blocks that represent it, and that's what I want to understand, I'm looking for either an explanation that will clarify the process, or some source that explains how to do it.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/141180/11684

@ScottSeidman Thanks, but the post you linked is more akin to the problems I was solving last semester where it was at the logic gate level, here at the register level of abstraction I cant draw karnough maps to find redundancy, or the other stuff expected from me this course and with the problems I'll face.

The way I usually implement state machines in code is with a switch case statement.

@ScottSeidman I'm not supposed to do it with code, just pen and paper

This kind of question is hard to answer, since it would describe a mental approach specifically for you. This is actually impossible for us without knowing you in detail. Any other type of answer would be opinionated as it provides ways that worked for other individuals. You might want to look for a forum (this site is not a forum) to discuss your way of inventing.

@thebusybee, I see, what you say makes sense, I was looking for the opinions of people here since given a large enough amount of people explaining their way of thinking about it would guarantee at least one of those would resonate with me, and "click",
may I ask if you know of good forums to ask such questions?
